# Can't get drop down list value from html in php

Tags: php, html, drop-down-menu

My first php code gets the values from the table "mytable" which are January, February and March respectively. It works well, I could see Month,January,February and March inside the drop down list. My problem is within the second php code, when I click the search button, nothing happens. What I expected it to do was print out the value from the drop down list but sadly, I get nothing.

```
<select name="monthchoice">
<option value="">Month</option>; 

<?php   
$request="SELECT date FROM mytable WHERE username='qwe'";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $request);
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo '<option value="'.$fetch['date'].'">'.$fetch['date'].'</option>'; 
}
?>

</select>
<input type="submit" value="Search" name="submit"/>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    if(!empty($_POST['monthchoice']))
        {
        $monthchoice1=$_POST['monthchoice'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo $monthchoice1;
        }
    else
        {
        echo "<br>";
        echo 'Please choose a month!';
        }
}
?>
```

Comment: Oh crap I forgot to put the submit button inside a form, that's why  I'm not getting anything! Lemme try to fix it.

Comment: hahaha, sometimes we could absolutely afford to solve our own problem..

Comment: The semicolon in `<option value="">Month</option>;` should not be there... Also, do you at least get "Please choose a month!"?

Comment: @Fev Haha it's a great feeling when you debug your own problems and get the reaction "How could I possibly miss this??!?!"

Comment: @ Robert Rossmann I got it working after I put the drop down list and submit button inside a form. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you wrapped your select and input inside a form tag with method post?

```
<form action="" method="post">
<select name="monthchoice">
<option value="">Month</option>; 

<?php   
$request="SELECT date FROM mytable WHERE username='qwe'";
$result=mysqli_query($con, $request);
while($fetch = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
{
echo '<option value="'.$fetch['date'].'">'.$fetch['date'].'</option>'; 
}
?>

</select>
<input type="submit" value="Search" name="submit"/>

<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"]))
{
    if(!empty($_POST['monthchoice']))
        {
        $monthchoice1=$_POST['monthchoice'];
        echo "<br>";
        echo $monthchoice1;
        }
    else
        {
        echo "<br>";
        echo 'Please choose a month!';
        }
}
?>

</form>
```

Comment: Thank you! I kept reading and reading my code to see where I could have possibly went wrong, I was too focused on the php and failed to check my html code. And after realizing that there wasn't even a form to begin with, I immediately placed it and was pleased with the results.

Comment: An easy mistake to make, sometimes it is the small stuff that mess up your code. thanks for checking my answer as the correct one. :)

Answer (score 1):

I think you don't use the tag form.

Comment: Yeah after obsessively reading every word in my code I realized I didn't use a form. I would like to say thank you since your answer is right.